# How to print a Struct in the Http Response in go lang

Tags: http, struct, go, httpresponse, postman

I am using POSTMAN for handling POST requests in go lang. I wish to display the response in the struct format(A struct of json data). 
For displaying a normal string, I am using `rw.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %s!", t.Name)))`

What should I do to display the **Struct in response body?(using rw.write method)**

`fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)` outputs to `{ID:1 Name:John Smith Address:123 Main St City:San Francisco State:CA Zip:94113 Coordinate:{Latitude:37.7917618 Longitude:-122.3943405}}`

This is what I want to display exactly in the Postman response .

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You kind of answered your own question implicitly, but I'll try to make it more clear in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you have indirectly answered your question but just didn't know about it.

You mentioned this example, which has the function you're looking for. `fmt.Sprintf` returns a formatted string instead of the one you were already using that prints to standard out, `fmt.Printf`.

> rw.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %s!", t.Name)))

So instead of `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)`, you can use something like the below that uses `fmt.Sprintf`:

```
structString := fmt.Sprintf("%+v\n", m)
rw.Write([]byte(structString))
```

The other solution as @JimB suggested is to use `fmt.Fprintf` directly taking an `io.Writer` as its first parameter and a format string afterwards.

```
fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%+v\n", *m)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Will C for your inputs. 
Now the struct prints as I want but it is preceded by a '&' character. ( as if it is a pointer).
The output is : &{ID:1 Name:John Smith Address:123 Main St City:San Francisco State:CA Zip:94113 Coordinate:{Latitude:37.7917618 Longitude:-122.3943405}}

Comment: I think thats because `m` happens to be a pointer so you might be able to do `fmt.Sprintf("%+v\n", *m)` to dereference `m`.

Comment: No need for the extra string conversion, `fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%+v\n", m)`

Comment: Good call! @JimB's suggestion is probably better. I'll update my answer to include it.